# event and process(question)

Tags: probability

Let $N_t$ a renewal process with $S_n=X_1+...+X_n$ the jumps. Let $A_t=t-S_{N_t-1}$ and $B_t=S_{N_t}-t$

How to show $ \{B_t \leq u \}= \{A_{t+u}<u \}$?

Thank you